# InstantListFilter In SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-foundation

Is there an equivalent to http://instantlistfilter.codeplex.com solutions available for SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

I use:

https://datatables.net/

Pretty easy to use, and has a lot of users, so if you have any trouble you can search and find an easy solution for your issue. And also is based on javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Nice! Do you have an example of the filter-as-you-type using datatables in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Yes: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html